# Task::ConfigureAwait - a race condition?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, race-condition

Imagine a sitution when caller creates a task:

```
{
 var tWithCapturedCtx = Task.Run(...);
 var tWithoutCapturedCtx = tWithCapturedCtx.ConfigureAwait(false);

 await tWithoutCapturedCtx;
}
```

Is there a possibility that tWithCapturedCtx will execute so fast that the continuation will be executed on the captured context?

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question and likely invalidated existing / accepted answers. Please avoid such edits - feel free to ask new question if you feel that you did not properly express your problem. Consider reverting the change.

Comment: @user3284063: I have rolled back your edit, since it is asking a different question. Please feel free to post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility that tWithCapturedCtx will execute so fast that the continuation will be executed on the captured context?

Sort of.

If `tWithCapturedCtx` is already finished by the time the `await` is evaluated (which means `tWithoutCapturedCtx` is also already finished), then there is no continuation at all. The `async` method just continues executing synchronously (on the same context).

However, if `tWithCapturedCtx` is not already finished by the time the `await` is evaluated (which means `tWithoutCapturedCtx` is also not already finished), then the continuation is scheduled without the context being captured.

There's another, even smaller, race condition between when the `await` checks if its awaitable is complete and when `await` schedules the continuation. If the awaitable completes within that window, then the continuation is just run synchronously (again, on the same context).

In conclusion, `ConfigureAwait(false)` means "I don't care what context the rest of this method runs in"; it does *not* mean "run the rest of this method on the thread pool". If you want to say "run this other code on a thread pool thread", then use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Allright, thanks. Another question: why didn't they put continueOnCapturedContext parameter into the signature of Task::Run method? That way the original task would be constructed with precise knowledge on which context to finish.

Comment: @user3284063: Because it's not the task's responsibility. Only the *calling* code knows whether it needs to resume on the captured context or not. It's "configure await", not "configure task".

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigureAwait` is being called *before the continuation is even being added to the task*.  The continuation is being added to the object that is configured to not capture the  context, so it is not going to capture the context when its continuation is run (that's literally what it exists to do, it wouldn't be fulfilling its documented purpose if it didn't).